# Showing images centered and not resized

Tags: html, css

I am working on a new e-commerce site.

On the home page there is a section to show the featured products.

[image]

There I have an issue related to the output from the product images.
I would like to show them centered and maintaining the proportions, not being resized.
This is my the current piece of code that shows the images:

```
<div class="thumb">
   <div style=" max-width:100%; height:auto; background-color:red;text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">
   <img  src="assets/uploads/<?php echo $row['p_featured_photo']; ?>" width="250" height="250">
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
 </div>
```

What should I change to get all images centered at not resized?

As example, here you have the needed output for the product number 4

[image]

EDIT

Removing the fixed sizes for the image tag, then the output from the images is correct, but not the product box sizes, the output is then as follows:

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to post the rest of your code in a runnable snippet in order to test/diagnose?

Comment: I have edited my question to show the output removing the img fixed width and height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule `object-fit: contain;` will help in solving your problem. Add it to your `<img>` tag and your images will be proportioned:

```
<img style="object-fit: contain;" src="" width="250" height="250">
```

```html
<div class="thumb">
   <div style=" max-width:100%; height:auto; background-color:red;text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">
   <img style="object-fit: contain;"  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv5BS.png" width="250" height="250">
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I have edited my question to show the output removing the img fixed width and height

Comment: @mvasco, you need to set a specific height for the container with images.

Comment: Your proposal is not working, same output

Comment: @mvasco, `try object-fit: contain;` for `img`, but assuming your images are vertically centered. Or `max-width: 100%` for `img`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `object-fit` property [read more >](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)

Comment: I have edited my question to show the output removing the img fixed width and height

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the problem is that you are setting a fixed width and height for your `img` elements. Therefore the images resize exactly to the specified size and look unnatural. You can remove your width and height attributes from your `img` tag and try another approach (for example wrap it with a div, which has width and height set).

```html
<div class="thumb">
   <div style=" max-width:100%; height:auto; background-color:red;text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">
     <div style="width: 250px; height: 250px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <img style="width:100%;" src="assets/uploads/<?php echo $row['p_featured_photo']; ?>"></div>
     </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
 </div>
```

In this solution you wrap your `img` tag with an additional `div` tag and set it's style to `width: 250px; height: 250px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`. Also you remove the fixed width and height from the `img` tag as mentioned above and add `width: 100%;` to it.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the output removing the img fixed width and height

Comment: I have edited my answer so you get the exact result as in the original code, except for the image problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply fix height all images and set object image

```
img{
   height: 250px;
   object-fit: contain;
}
```